# Replacement for c0-change-interval

Tags: tmux

I used to use the line below in my `.tmux.conf` to keep it from trying to render every line on output, and only update the screen 3 times a second.

```
setw -g c0-change-interval 333
```

What's the replace ment for it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no replacement, the problem it was intended to solve has been addressed in a different way (or in fact several - by tracking the amount of data the terminal is waiting to consume and redrawing instead, by not redrawing until all previous data has been consumed, by omitting changes that would have no visible effect on the terminal, and by batching strings of characters together).